# Entity Framework Detached multiple many-to-many Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

Usually, a page would have a single main entity and have child entities. I had a solution before for this type of detached many-to-many

e.g.

```
db.Entry(Class).State = EntityState.Modified;
foreach(var student in Class.student) {
  var dbStudent = db.Students.Find(student.StudentID);
  dbStudent.Classes.Add(Class);
}
```

My problem is I have multiple Classes in the view and is causing "entity of the same type already has the same primary key value"

e.g. looping the List of Classes

```
foreach(var class in viewModel.Classes) {
  db.Entry(Class).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Above code will throw the error on reaching the 2nd class if the same student is present in both classes. Its because assigning the EntityState also loads it child entities and create 2 instances of the same student.

I tried to manipulate this by creating a temporary collection so that it will only have a single instance

e.g.

```
var students = new List<students>();
foreach(var class in viewModel.Classes) {
  foreach(var student in class.Students) {
     Student dbStudent = null;
     if(!students.Any(s => s.StudentID == student.StudentID)) {
      dbStudent = db.Student.Find(student.StudentID);
      students.Add(dbStudent);
      db.Entry(dbStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
    } 
    else {
      dbStudent = students.Where(s => s.StudentID == student.StudentID).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    dbStudent.Classes.Add(class);
  }
  db.Entry(class).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

The code above works well for new entries, but for existing entries it causes a "Primary Key error" which for me says that It is detached. This will also not work when trying to remove an existing entry.

Anybody can help me here? Thanks

Comment: It maybe a silly question but why are you changing the student state to modified?

Comment: I think the problem here isn't so much your code as the database structure... don't you have a link table with the two foreign keys?

Comment: I have. but I let EntityFramework do that for me.

Comment: I set the student to modified since I added a new class after it was loaded from the db/context. I have to set that to modified if I want changes to reflect

Comment: dbStudent.Add(class); you are adding a Class entity to an entity type Student ? How does that work out for you?

Comment: Try db.Set<Students>().Attach(dbStudent); before you add students.Add(dbStudent);

Comment: should've been dbStudent.Classes.Add(Class); the sample code is kind of a pseudo. cant post actual code :)

Comment: do I need to attach the student? the dbStudent comes from the db.Students.Find(student.StudentID); This should be already attached. I also tried to attach the Class entity since when I tried to db.Detach(Class), it threw an error that it the entity is not attached. When I attached the class, the results were still the same